# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object when I submit data to DB in Oracle asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, executenonquery

I have a method where I want to execute a stored procedure and get the status and response from it. When executing my `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, I am getting an error:

> operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

This is the code:

```
public static string GET_IPL_STATUS_ON_NEID(string NEID)
{
        string strStatus = string.Empty; string strMessage = string.Empty;

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringAppAuto"].ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GET_IP_STATUS_PROC"].ToString();

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_A6_NEID", Value = NEID, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "STATUS",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                Size = 500,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "MESSAGE",
                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                Size = 500,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            });

            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) conn.Open();
            
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            strStatus = cmd.Parameters["STATUS"].Value.ToString();
            strMessage = cmd.Parameters["MESSAGE"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
        }

        return strStatus;            
}
```

Comment: You never assigned the connection to the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [example in the `OracleCommand` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/OracleCommandClass.html#GUID-7C1D5BCC-0268-4F1B-A583-F401F30EB9C0), you need to set the `Connection` property on the command to tell it which connection to use:

```c#
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GET_IP_STATUS_PROC"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks MT0, it worked. Forgot that small part.!!